# Delta Lake Size Requirements

Tags: delta-lake, data-lakehouse, delta-rs

Does delta lake store the changes within file, or just of whole files? Does it just record an deletion of the previous table and an addition of a new, modified table? Or does it record insert/update/deletes on the row level?

Suppose you have a 100MiB table and you change a single row representing 1KiB of data, and you make 100 such changes. Will it take up approximately 100 * 1KiB of space or 100 * 100MiB?

This may depend on the engine, so an answer that differs by engine is acceptable.

Comment: Files in Delta storage are immutable. So if you make 100 changes each saved separately, it will copy file 100 times. Solution is to batch 100 changes into single update OR partition database into smaller files so on save only modified file will be copied. Remember, if your Delta is not append-only then VACUUM operation is essential.

Comment: I'm confused: aren't there file-level changes that record only the changes in the file, not the file itself? Can you please cite the docs?

Comment: See "writes" section https://docs.delta.io/latest/concurrency-control.html#optimistic-concurrency-control

Comment: This states that there is a command "UPDATE", much like sql. Are you saying that an update isn't stored efficiently, but each item in the history takes as much memory as the entire table? The documentation never states how the update history is stored. **This is not an answer because it does not state the memory usage**.

Comment: "takes as much memory as the entire table" - no, as much as entire file. Table can be partitioned and each partition can have many files and Delta will only copy modified files.

Comment: "This is not an answer because it does not state the memory usage." - what memory do you refer? Delta only uses disk/storage space.

Comment: yes, disk memory

Comment: Before I give up, there is one more link https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#operation-metrics-keys There you can see what Delta writes to the metadata on every operation. For UPDATE it writes `numAddedFiles`, `numRemovedFiles` (i.e. no updated files) and `numUpdatedRows`, `numCopiedRows` - notice last one. If it does in-place update, what is "copied rows"?

Comment: That shows there is a number of copied rows, but **it does not say that the history stores all of the copied rows.** It states only that the rows are copied when instantiating the table. I did more research and I'm pretty convinced you're wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With [Deletion Vectors](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-deletion-vectors.html) enabled on version 2.3.0+ of the Spark connector, only the row-level deltas are written out so that mutating operations like `DELETE` and `UPDATE` do not always cause entire files to be written out.

Without this feature enabled, you'd rewrite entire files. Taking your example of a table with total size 100MiB and constantly rewriting a 1KiB file, you'd rewrite that 1KiB file 100 times, resulting in 100KiB of re-writes.

With deletion vectors, you'd write a fraction of this, I found a single-value vector file to be ~50 bytes, which is 1/20 the size of your given situation, resulting in 5KiB of writes total. This ratio is already large but becomes a larger factor with real deployments, where files are in the MiB/GiB range, becoming a 5-6 order of magnitude difference in the amount of data written.

Comment: What if you do only 100 additions, not delete or update?

Comment: Without more detail, I can say that you'd then be adding 100 very tiny files.

Answer (score -1):

Delta lake efficiently stores the history as updates to individual rows, not a copy of the table for every change. So it will take O(100 * 1KiB).

Comment: It was me. I will remove it if you expand your answer proving that Delta does not copy any data. Here is another link from Delta devs https://delta.io/blog/2022-12-07-delete-rows-from-delta-lake-table/, please read carefully and see how "ingrid" is copied to file C.

Comment: "not a copy of the table for every change." - also, I'm bringing your attention that at no point I was saying "copy table for every change". Delta table is split into multiple files and it only copies data from files which are being impacted by UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE/OPTIMIZE. It is why it does not copy anything on INSERT - because no previous files are impacted.